# Analog of $PWD in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I run windows command in particular directory and I need to pass files and subdirectories in this directory with full path. How to retrieve full path of current directory? What is analog of bash $PWD?

Comment: `Get-Location` ?

Comment: If working in bat files [pushd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [popd](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) often come in handy too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$pwd` is indeed a valid command in PowerShell as well (if you're using PowerShell). `$pwd` in PowerShell is basically an alias for `Get-Location` - both of them will give you the full path of current directory.

In case you are using cmd, use `cd` (just `cd` without any parameters)

Comment: There is also %CD% for CMD

Comment: @filimonic - This is not the way to do what OP wants. If you are including something between 2 percentage (%) symbols, the Command Prompt treats it as a name of variable and tries to replace it with the value of that variable.

Comment: `pwd`  =  `cd`       ..... and ......          `$(pwd) ` =  `%cd%`